# How to find a string between two substring?

Tags: php, string

I have a text.

> \cf1\i ( Wong v. Tenneco, Inc. (1985) 39 Cal.3d 126, 135 [216
>   Cal.Rptr. 412, 702 P.2d 570]; Knodel v. Knodel (1975) 14 Cal.3d 752,
>   765, fn. 15 [122 Cal.Rptr. 521, 537 P.2d 353].)\cf0\i0 This approach
>   was enunciated long ago by Justice Cardozo, who explained that courts
>   will not refuse to enforce a foreign cause of action unless
>   application of the foreign law 'would violate some fundamental
>   principle of justice, some prevalent conception of good morals, some
>   deep-rooted tradition of the common weal.' \cf1\i ( Loucks v. Standard
>   Oil Co. (1918) 224 N.Y. 99, 111 [120 N.E. 198, 202].)\cf0\i0
>   California case, \cf1\i Bryant v. Mead (1851) 1 Cal. 441\cf0\i0

here: I have

```
$1st  = "\cf1\i"; 
$2nd = "\cf0\i0";
```

these two substring. I have to find a string starting with `$1st` and ending with `$2nd` in this text though this text is dynamic, and I don't know how many times these two substrings will appear.

I did this : `$between=substr($str, strpos($str, $1st) + 6, strpos($str, $2nd) - strpos($str, $1st) + 1);`

but I give only the first string.

How can I get all the strings starting with `$1st` and ending with `$2nd` in this text?

Comment: *do my homework please...* > No, show code you tried, and where you failed. -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From:  http://www.justin-cook.com/wp/2006/03/31/php-parse-a-string-between-two-strings/

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

$fullstring = "this is my [tag]dog[/tag]";
$parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, "[tag]", "[/tag]");

echo $parsed; // (result = dog)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. but if I want to find those "[tag]" and "[/tag]" more than one In that same text than what will I need to do.

Comment: I wrote a function for this awhile back, but don't have the source code on me at the moment.  You can easily modify this function to have it keep searching, and return an array of results.

Answer (score 0):

I just modify your code and find the answere. here is my code:

```
$fullstr = "this is my [tag]dog[/tag].this is my [tag]this is my dog[/tag].this is my [tag]this is my dog[/tag]";
$start = "[tag]";
$end = "[/tag]";

    $first = substr_count($fullstr, $start);
    $second = substr_count($fullstr, $end);

    function get_string_between($string, $start, $end)
     {
        $string = " ".$string;
        $ini = strpos($string,$start);
        if ($ini == 0) return "";
        $ini += strlen($start);
        $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
        return substr($string,$ini,$len);
    }


    $i=0;

    while($i<=$first)
    {
        $occur = strpos($fullstr, $val5, $i);
        echo $between = get_string_between($fullstr, $val7, $val5);

        $fullstr= substr($fullstr, $occur, 100000);

     $i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<?php

$str = "...server daemon started with pid=6849 (parent=6848).";
$from = "pid=";
$to = "(";

echo getStringBetween($str,$from,$to);

function getStringBetween($str,$from,$to)
{
    $sub = substr($str, strpos($str,$from)+strlen($from),strlen($str));
    return substr($sub,0,strpos($sub,$to));
}

?>
```