# Getting a description from another website using PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to grab this description which is on a website using preg_match just having issues:

Here is what i'm trying to grab. Just the text after `<b>Game Description:</b><br />` upto `<b>Tool v3.1 Info:`

```
<b>Game Description:</b><br />
Steel Diver is a new action-packed submarine combat game from Nintendo that<br />
immerses players in the 3D action with unique game controls and lush 3D<br />
environments. The player can choose from three different submarines, each<br />
with touch-screen control panels that players will have to master to guide<br />
them through treacherous undersea caverns while engaging enemy submarines,<br />
dodging depth charges and battling massive sea creatures. Steel Diver also<br />
takes advantage of the built-in gyroscope of the Nintendo 3DS system. The<br />
combination of 3D game play and one-of-a-kind controls makes for an immersive<br />
combination that must be experienced to be believed.<br />
<br />
<b>Tool v3.1 Info:
```

**Heres what I've tried:**

```
    $pattern1 = '#<b>Game Description:</b><br />\s*(.*?)\s*<b>Tool v3.1 Info:#';
    preg_match($pattern1,$downloadPage,$description);
    print_r($description);
```

`$downloadPage`     is just opening the URL using curl, I've got it grabbing some other data, Just need help with this part.

Thanks

Comment: Just use a function like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8010000/2100549

Comment: Where do you set the variable `$description`?

Comment: Sorry check now, was a typo. How can i make that function work with getting data from a website?

Comment: @Barmar - $description is the matches array

Comment: @user602525 He edited the question after I asked. The matches array was `$match_description` at that time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the [`s` modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to match over multiple lines:

```
$pattern1 = '#<b>Game Description:</b><br />\s*(.*?)\s*<b>Tool v3.1 Info:#s';
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/80414)